# Passing args from Razor Page to a Razor Component

Tags: c#, parameters, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

## The scenario

I've created a Razor Pages project and added server side blazor rendering so that I can add Razor Components. I am having an issue where `_Layout.cshtml` renders a razor component on the page and passes an argument to it, yet at runtime, the razor component appears to ***not*** receive an argument for this parameter.

## Example with actual output

### `_Layout.cshtml`

```razor
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

            
<body>
    IP ON GET WAS: @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress
    <component type="typeof(MyFormComponent)" IPAddress="@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress" render-mode="ServerPrerendered"/>

</body>
</html>
```

When the website renders, the visitor's IP address is displayed directly above the component. (I'm doing this purely to prove to myself that `_Layout.cshtml`, the page rendering the razor component, does indeed have access to a concrete working child of `IHttpContextAccessor`.)

### `MyFormComponent.razor`

```razor
@using System


<button type="button" @onclick="doStuff">
    Click Me 
</button>


@code
{

    [Parameter]
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }

    private void doStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We've got the IP! -> " + this.IPAddress);
        // prints: "We've got the IP! -> "
    }
}
```

When the above button is clicked on the component, `this.IPAddress` is `null`. I've checked this value on a breakpoint while debugging and I've observed that the IP address is not printed to the console.

## The expected output

I expected that my razor component would receive the argument value passed to it and print it to the console whenever the button is clicked. I expected that `_Layout.cshtml` would be able to pass this value to the razor component because it has proven that it does indeed have access to the desired value I want to pass by displaying the value on the page.

#### Closing notes

- This was initially a Razor Pages project, created via `dotnet new webapp`.
- Server side blazor was introduced to the project and has been working with great success, with this issue being the only exception so far. So, the project does have a `_Host.cshtml` and `_Imports.razor` file, along with the `AddServerSideBlazor()` call in `Startup.ConfigureServices()`, and the `MapBlazorHub()` endpoint added in `Startup.Configure()`. I didn't think it would be necessary to share the contents of these files for this specific problem. If I'm wrong about this, please, let me know!
- You might notice that this issue specifically involves a reference to `IHttpContextAccessor`. If you were not aware, this specific class is NOT to be accessed directly from within a razor component [for the reasons described here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-and-shared-state)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the solution to this problem is simply an alternate syntax being used to render the razor component in the `_Layout.cshtml` file.

By replacing (the current code)

```cs
<component type="typeof(MyFormComponent)" IPAddress="@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress" render-mode="ServerPrerendered"/>
```

with the following (a new snippet):

```cs
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<MyFormComponent>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered, new { IPAddress=HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()}))
```

I was able to resolve this issue.